# How to store the results of tokenization for further indexing?

Tags: python, indexing, search-engine, information-retrieval

I am totally a beginner and now trying to implement a simple `search engine in python`.

I doing the `tokenizer` well by used functions in `NLTK`. But I am now confused on storing the results of the tokenizer. I need to keep them for further indexing.

What's the common way to do this? What kind of database should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Introduction to Information Retrieval*](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/irbook.html) by Manning, Raghavan and Schütze devotes several chapters to index construction and storage; so does [*Modern Information Retrieval*](http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~hearst/irbook/) by Baeza-Yates and Ribeiro-Neto.

For a simple hobby/study project, though, [SQLite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) will suffice for index storage. You need a table that holds (term, document-id, frequency) triples to compute tf and one that stores (term, df) pairs, both with an index on the terms; that's enough to compute tf-idf.

Comment: Thanks for you tips! I accomplished it!